# Add/Append a column as first column to a tab delimited file

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a <kbd>Tab</kbd> separated file as follows:

```
A      B
HM     1
BN     2
```

I would like to add another column to this file such that this new column becomes the first column of the file as shown below:

```
New        A       B
201507     HM      1
201507     BN      2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste`:

```
paste -d"\t" file1 file2
```

Where:

- `-d` specifies the dlimiter between the two files (`\t` is a tabulator).
- `file1` contains the lines you want to prepend.
- `file2` contains the other lines.

**Edit**: Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{getline l < "file2"; print $0"\t"l} ' file1
```

Where:

- getline reads the next line from `file2` into the variable called `l`, which is then printed after the line of `file1` followed by a tab `\t`.

When `file1` would contain:

```
New
201507
201507
```

...and `file2` contains:

```
A      B
HM     1
BN     2
```

...the output would be:

```
New     A      B
201507  HM     1
201507  BN     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not seem to be having the paste command... Not sure why. I am working from a company system.

Comment: @activelearner What os are you running on that system?

Comment: Linux hostname 2.6.32-358.41.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 21 15:58:42 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @activelearner See my edit, I added an `awk` solution.